# Protractor testing- ng-click with parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

How do I test test a `ng-click` function with a parameter inside within an ng-repeat using protractor with this format:

```js
<span ng-repeat = "name in names">
  <a ng-click = "editName(name)"></a>
</span>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  The fact that the click takes a parameter shouldn't cause any particular problems for a protractor test.

Answer (score 0):

As @P.T. pointed out, `protractor` works on a higher level and it should not matter what is the logic behind the click. Here is how you can click each link inside the repeater:

```
element.all(by.repeater("name in names")).each(function (elm) {
    var link = elm.element(by.css("a[ng-click*=editName]"));
    link.click();

    // assertions/expectations
});
```